# Reach Deployment server through SSH tunnel

Tags: webstorm, ssh-tunnel

I'm developing javascript applications in Webstorm. For now I am connecting to a remote deployment server through sftp. (tools > deployment)

For security reasons we want to do it this way:
First make an ssh connection (tunnel) to server1, and from there connect to server2/devFolder.

Is this possible in Webstorm? Any plug-ins?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it isn't possible directly with Webstorm, you can always make a tunnel through server1 to server2 with ssh.  You do need an account on both servers, and you need to setup agent forwarding, so you don't need your private key on server1.

I do this frequently.

Let's say server2 is on a private network only accessible from server1, here's how you'd setup a tunnel to server2 (assume it's 10.0.0.5, and x.x.x.x is the ip of server1 on your workstation:

```
ssh -f you@x.x.x.x -L 2022:10.0.0.5:22 -N
```

Now that you have the tunnel up, just connect with Webstorm using localhost:2022.

The only thing you need in Webstorm to make this work is the ability to change the default sftp port in the config to 2022.

Comment: That is possibly good working set-up. But we prefer not, to open unnecessary ports to one of the servers in the local network.

Comment: This doesn't open up any ports, it uses a tunnel through ssh on your workstation.